# How to apply not operator to all matrix elements in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, negate

I need to apply "not" operator to matrix of zeros and ones in Julia.
In Matlab I would do this:

```
A=not(B);
```

In Julia I tried doing this:

```
A = .~ B;
```

and

```
A = .! B;
```

It should turn zeros to ones and ones to zeros but I get error as a result or all matrix elements are some negative numbers that I didn't enter.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with `A = .!B` is that logical negation, `!(::Int64)`, isn't defined for integers. This makes sense: What should, say, `!3` reasonably give?

Since you want to perform a logical operation, is there a deeper reason why you are working with integers to begin with?

You could perhaps work with a `BitArray` instead which is vastly more efficient and should behave like a regular `Array` in most operations.

You can easily convert your integer matrix to a `BitArray`. Afterwards, applying a logical not works as expected.

```
julia> A = rand(0:1, 5,5)
5×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0  1  1
 0  1  0  0  1
 0  1  1  1  0
 1  1  0  0  0
 1  1  1  0  0

julia> B = BitArray(A)
5×5 BitArray{2}:
 0  0  0  1  1
 0  1  0  0  1
 0  1  1  1  0
 1  1  0  0  0
 1  1  1  0  0

julia> .!B
5×5 BitArray{2}:
 1  1  1  0  0
 1  0  1  1  0
 1  0  0  0  1
 0  0  1  1  1
 0  0  0  1  1
```

The crucial part here is that the element type (`eltype`) of a `BitArray` is `Bool`, for which negation is obviously well defined. In this sense, you could also use `B = Bool.(A)` to convert all the elements to booleans.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! 
I perfectly understand it now. I wanted to perform logical negation to only zeros and ones, I know that it isn't defined for integers, but I didn't know how to do it and that BitArray command exists... Thank you for great answer!

Comment: I feel like recommending `BitArray` obscures the issue a bit.  If you only have 0s and 1s, use `Bool.(B)` to convert all elements to logical values on which you can do logical operations.  It does indeed _also_ return a `BitArray` in most cases, but it's also a bit clearer _why_ it does the trick IMO.

Comment: In other words — it's not about the array type at all!  It's about the _element types_.

Comment: @MattB. Thank you very much! I will try that, too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Matt. I'll update my answer and try to clarify things a bit more.

Answer (score 6):

For a general solution to going from `A` where `A` is a matrix of numbers to a boolean matrix with true values where there were zeros and false values elsewhere, you can do this:

```
julia> A = rand(0:3, 5, 5)
5×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  1  0  3
 2  0  1  1  0
 2  1  1  3  1
 1  0  3  0  3
 1  3  3  1  2

julia> (!iszero).(A)
5×5 BitArray{2}:
 1  0  1  0  1
 1  0  1  1  0
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  0  1  0  1
 1  1  1  1  1
```

To break down what's going on here:

- `iszero` is a predicate that tests if a scalar value is zero
- `!iszero` is a predicate that returns if a scalar value is not zero
- `(!iszero).(A)` broadcasts the `!iszero` function over the matrix `A`

This returns a `BitArray` with the desired pattern of zeros (falses) and ones (trues). Note that in an array context, false prints as `0` and true prints as `1` (they are numerically equal). You can also compare with the number `0` like this:

```
julia> A .!= 0
5×5 BitArray{2}:
 1  0  1  0  1
 1  0  1  1  0
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  0  1  0  1
 1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice alternative! I will try it, too. 
I definitely learned a lot about Julia today!

Answer (score 3):

You can also roll your own:

```
not(x) = (x |> Bool |> !) |> Float64
```

defines a method that will convert `x` to `boolean`, apply not, and then convert the result back to numbers. `not.(A)` will act element-wise on the array `A`. Here `|>` redirects the output to the next method and works with broadcasting.

Comment: Thank you very much! Love your solution! I will use this logic, too. Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

While not conceptually the cleanest, `A=1.-B` will do what you want. The problem with `~` is that it is performing a bitwise not on integers, which produces negative numbers. Not sure what is wrong wiht `!` except it maybe should be `!.B`

Comment: `A=1 .- B`  is a great idea! I didn't think of that. It gets the job done. I tried ` !.B` , too but it doesn't work. Thank you for smart solution!